# How to handle the null check operator exception?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a simple Todo App, here is my code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/screens/new_task.dart';

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_myHomeState createState() => _myHomeState();
}

 class _myHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
 String uid = ' ';
 @override
 void initState() {
 getUid();
 super.initState();
  }

 getUid() async {
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final User? user = await auth.currentUser;
 setState(() {
    uid = user!.uid;
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('TODO'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.white10,
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('tasks')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('myTasks')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [Text(docs[index]['title'])],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    ),
      ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTask()));
    },
   ),
   );
  }
 }
```

Only one point, I am using null check operator, first `setState(() { uid = user!.uid;});}`
When I remove this, flutter throws the error to put the null check operator.
So, please help me, I am a beginner........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: what's the issue that you are facing here if you add the null check operator? it just checks if the user is null.

Comment: E/flutter (15911): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (15911): #0      _myHomeState.getUid.<anonymous closure> (package:todo_app/screens/home.dart:25:17)
E/flutter (15911): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1121:30)
E/flutter (15911): #2      _myHomeState.getUid (package:todo_app/screens/home.dart:24:5)
E/flutter (15911): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: cause of this, not showing the tasks which are coming to the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `user!.uid;` use `user?.uid ?? "";`. If you use ? it means that the user can be null

Comment: It is throwing an error.    Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
      uid = user?.uid;
            ^

Comment: Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Sir, it works, no exception now, but according to the ListView.builder, should be shown the tasks which are coming from the firebase, but they are not showing on the screen.

Comment: Just after setstate in getuid can you print the uid and see if you recieved the uid

Comment: Sir, not printing uid this mean, not coming  the uid.

Comment: Please check firebase implementation and if you have missed something

Comment: Thanks for your precious time Sir. I will check that.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer that helped you resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

and if you use `user?.uid;` sometimes it requires default value, so in that case you can set a default value `user?.uid ?? "Information Not Available"` for not getting error.

Comment: ir, it works, no exception now, but according to the ListView.builder, should be shown the tasks which are coming from the firebase, but they are not showing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is user can be null because it is of the type `User?`. The question mark means its value is nullable (i.e. it can be null). You likely want to make it of type `User`, instead of `User?`.

Comment: It throws an error.error: A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'. (invalid_assignment at [todo_app] lib\screens\home.dart:23)

Comment: that means that the data that user receives can be null so it is best to leave it with User?, instead of changing that, change this user!.uid for user?.uid and String uid = ' ' for String? uid = ' '

Comment: Sir, listen when I add space between ' ' in  String? uid = ' ' : it throws an error, a document path must be a non-empty string

Comment: And when I add space my stack is.... W/DynamiteModule(15911): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.provider installer.dynamite not found.
W/2.raster(15911): type=1400 audit(0.0:52925): avc: denied { search } for name="power_supply" dev="sysfs" ino=9959 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c244,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs_power:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
I/DynamiteModule(15911): Considering local module

Comment: com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(15911): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
 no error no exception but not showing tasks on the screen from the firebase

Comment: try not giving it an initial value and adding late
late String? uid;

Comment: Thanks for your precious time Sir. not solving the error, but I will try again and again.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re sure that an expression with a nullable type isn’t null, you can

`add !` to make Dart treat it as non-nullable.

`user?.uid` this means you expect user model has uid value. and it should be there if not there it will give you an exception.

Example: Let,

`int? x;`

`x!` - confident value never be null.

`x??0` - If x is null, there it will be 0;

`if(x != null){ then use your x value }`

that's how null safety helps to handle nullable values in dart/flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the current firebase user is no longer async.  (It hasn't been for about a year.)  You're reading an old tutorial.  Please find one written in the the past nine months.